# Filter google query results

Tags: lucene, google-api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm writing a search engine for wikipedia articles using lucene on the wiki xml dump and I want to calculate the accuracy of the engine when compared to google wiki result on a particular query, when I give "site:en.wikipedia.org" along with the query. I want to do it for multiple queries so I'm getting the google search result URLs manually. I got Google APIs to use a bot to search Google but the problem is I want to get rid off certain type of results like 
"/Category:"
"/icon:"
"/file:"
"/photo:"
and user pages.

But I haven't found a convenient way to do this except for using an iterative method of issuing a query, get n number of results, then filter out by using regular expressions, then retrieve the remaining (n-x) results and so on. Google keeps blocking me when I do that.

Is there an intelligent way to get Google results the way I want using Java?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try excluding those pages from the Google results, like this:

- [*living people site:en.wikipedia.org -inurl:category -inurl:category_talk -inurl:file -inurl:file_talk -inurl:user -inurl:user_talk*](http://www.google.com/search?q=living+people+site%3aen.wikipedia.org+-inurl%3Acategory+-inurl%3Acategory_talk+-inurl%3Afile+-inurl%3Afile_talk+-inurl%3Auser+-inurl%3Auser_talk)